# Howto use WSO2 IS SOAP service call targeting only secondary user stores

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I target the WSO2 IS soap services against only a secondary user store?

For example, I have successfully used the "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" SOAP service to list users. How can I use the SOAP service to target only my secondary store?

```
configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);
        String serviceEndPoint = SERVER_URL + "RemoteUserStoreManagerService";
        RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub adminStub
                = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub(configContext, serviceEndPoint);

        ServiceClient client = adminStub._getServiceClient();
        Options option = client.getOptions();

        option.setProperty(HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, null);

        HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth
                = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
        auth.setUsername(USER_NAME);
        auth.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

        option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
        option.setManageSession(true);

        String[] users = adminStub.listUsers("*", 10);

        if (users != null) {
            for (String user : users) {
                System.out.println("Username : " + user);
            }
        }
```

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say there is a use store called  `FOO` then you need to pass the search pattern to list users as `FOO/*`

`adminStub.listUsers("FOO/*", 10);`

When you are using `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` , you can use `FOO/` prefix to retrieve data from `FOO` user store.

Say if you want to retrieve user attribute from a user in `FOO` then user name must be passed as `FOO/asela`

Comment: Thanks. Will this also work for adding users? Add user FOO/asela will add "asela" to the FOO user store?